# Why is my node count so high and climbing in Zookeeper?

Tags: java, apache, apache-zookeeper

When I run telnet `127.0.0.1 2181` and use the four letter command stat. Everything that gets printed out makes sense to me except for my Node count, which is at 542 and climbing every time I run my program.

Does this mean that I have persistent nodes lying around that I need to clean up?

I am using the O'Reilly Zookeeper book and I use the "AdminClient" class and I am printing out all the possible nodes and everything is deleted before my program closes using `zk.delete()`.

I am new to zookeeper so any ideas about what is going on or best practices is appreciated.

***UPDATE***
Does nobody have a method of inspecting the nodes in a zookeeper instance? There has to be a way to see what nodes exist without knowing the path beforehand.

Comment: You can view nodes (connected clients) with this command: echo status | nc 127.0.0.1 2181

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a command line utility /opt/zookeeper/current/bin/zkCli.sh that allows you to navigate zookeeper node hierarchy like a file system. Run it on any box that has ZK installed and then in ZK console use commands like ls, get, set, rmr etc. The full list of supported commands and tgeir syntax can be displayed by running help command. See http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperStarted.html for details

Answer (score 1):

It's znodes cf. https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.6/zookeeperProgrammers.html#sc_zkDataModel_znodes

```
$ echo srvr | nc localhost 2181

Zookeeper version: 3.3.0-925362, built on 03/19/2010 18:38 GMT
Latency min/avg/max: 0/8/76
Received: 17
Sent: 16
Outstanding: 0
Zxid: 0x300000002
Mode: follower
Node count: 4
```

- version is 3.3.0
- min/avg/max latencies for this server in milliseconds. This details the amount of time it takes for the server to respond to a client request.
- number of client requests (typically operations)
- received number of client packets sent (responses and notifications)
- outstanding is the number of queued requests, this increases when the server is under load and is receiving more sustained requests than it can process, ie the request queue
- zxid is the global (cluster wide) transaction identifier. The upper 32 bits of which are the epoch number (changes when leadership changes) and the lower 32 bits which are the xid proper
- mode indicates the serving mode, typically leader/follower but might be standalone if not running an ensemble
- node count is the number of znodes in the ZooKeeper namespace (the
  data)

taken from https://phunt1.wordpress.com/category/zookeeper/